# R Shiny Graphics Looking Awkward

Tags: r, shiny

I am running R version 4.2.1 and R Studio version 2022.07.2 (576). Any R Shiny app that I run locally produces an awkward looking greyed-out output which I am unable to fix. The app runs without errors or warnings and I am unable to troubleshoot. This happens to all my apps which in earlier R versions ran fine. As a reproducible example, please see below, followed by the output that I am getting. I am running the following code saved in my app.R file. Thank you very much in advance.

```
library(shiny)
toyota=data.frame(Price=c(100,200,300), Age=c(23,12,48), KM=c(200,120,400))
ui = fluidPage(titlePanel("Toyota Regression"),
               sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(selectInput(inputId = "num.predictor", label="Numeric Predictor",
                                                      choices=c("Age","KM"))),
                             mainPanel(plotOutput("Scatter"))))
               

server = function (input, output) {
  output$Scatter=renderPlot({plot(input$num.predictor, toyota$Price, ylab="Price", xlab=input$num.predictor)})
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce. What version of the `shiny` package are you using? Can you check the network tab of the developer tools to see if any requests are being blocked? The page should be loading CSS to do the styling.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In fact I was using an older version of shiny and after upgrading to the latest version (and fixing the bug that @r2evans noted) the app runs fine. Your comment answered my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check your console, you should be seeing an error

```r
Error: 'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

This is caused by your attempt to plot `input$num.predictor` (length-1, value `"Age"`) against a numeric vector (length-3 in this case). I think you intend to subset from `toyota`:

```r
server = function (input, output) {
  output$Scatter=renderPlot({plot(toyota[[input$num.predictor]], toyota$Price, ylab="Price", xlab=input$num.predictor)})
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Strangely, I was not even getting the error message in the console. After fixing the bug that you pointed out, I still was getting the greyed-out output that my initial post was about. The issue as @MrFlick pointed out was related to the version of shiny that I was using. After upgrading to the newest version (and following your fix) the app runs fine. Thanks very much.